# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash, winterbash-2016

It's nearly December, and Winter Bash is almost upon us.

For anyone not familiar with it, [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winterbash/info) is an end-of-the-year celebration on Stack Exchange, where users can earn "hats" to wear on their profile pictures by doing certain things.

Each site can choose whether or not to participate. However, unless there is a large consensus against participating, the site will automatically participate. Individual users who don't want to participate, don't want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

Winter Bash will run from December 19th through January 8th. Users will be able to see all the hats they've earned on [winterbash2016.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com).

So what do we say? Do we want hats this year?

<sup>Some of this was copied from [this similar post on HSM Meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/do-we-want-hats).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

## Yes! Let's have hats!

はい！私は帽子が好きです！
Sí, me gustan sombreros!
<sub>(feel free to add more...)</sub>

(Upvote to agree, downvote to disagree.)

Comment: Yes, let's try hats to enliven the community. We can use it.

Comment: I want a [language hat](http://languagehat.com/) ;-)   (Famous blog.)